# Want to create some kind of a loop for this code

Tags: c, loops

I'm new in programming I watched a tutorial for c (about 3 hours long) and I immediately  wrote this code. Now everything works fine, but I want to create some kind of loop, i will try to explain what I want as best as I can.

Here is a code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char *characterName;
    char *yes_no;

    characterName = malloc(sizeof(char));
    yes_no = malloc(sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter you name: ");
    scanf("%s", characterName);
    printf("Are you sure[Yes/No]: ");
    scanf("%s", yes_no);

    if(strcmp(yes_no, "Yes") == 0 || strcmp(yes_no, "yes") == 0)
    {
        printf("Your name is %s", characterName);
    }
    else if(strcmp(yes_no, "No") == 0 || strcmp(yes_no, "no") == 0)
    {
        printf("Try again!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unknown command!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What it does is it basically asks you to enter your name and then to confirm it, if you type Yes or yes it will print what your name is, if you type No or no it will print try again, if you enter something else but Yes/yes or No/no it will print unknown command. Now what I want to know is how I can make a loop that will repeat over and over unless I type in yes.
Like I entered no or unknown command I want it to ask me to enter my name again. I hope you can understand what I want to do and sorry for my bad English I'm still learning :D.

Comment: `characterName = malloc(sizeof(char));` You allocate memory only for a zero terminating character. There is no memory for a `yes` or `no` string. There is no memory to read a name into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you got a implicit declaration warning for strcmp there, missing `#include <string.h>`, but code compiles great and it does what it should do so far.

Now we add looping to it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *characterName;
    char *yes_no;

    characterName = malloc(sizeof(char));
    yes_no = malloc(sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter you name: ");
    scanf("%s", characterName);
    while(1) {
        printf("Are you sure[Yes/No]: ");
        scanf("%s", yes_no);

        if(strcmp(yes_no, "Yes") == 0 || strcmp(yes_no, "yes") == 0){
            printf("Your name is %s", characterName);
            break;
        }
        else if(strcmp(yes_no, "No") == 0 || strcmp(yes_no, "no") == 0){
            printf("Try again!");
        } else {
            printf("Unknown command!");
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

the code in the `while(1) { .. }` is always true ( 1 is true) untill you type 'yes' and the `break;` is hit.

there are some memory-allocation issues, as pointed out by commentators.

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/HJYRvokQH

Comment: Thank you very much, i like that you've put whole code with loop in it, because i'm new and i'm still learning. Appreciate it! :D

Answer (score 4):

Like most things in programming, there are many ways to do what you are asking.

One way is to introduce a new variable, called yes_entered or something similar, that will track if the user has entered yes yet. Then inside the if statement where you check if yes was entered you can set this variable to true. To make this into a loop you can put the code you want to repeat inside a `while(!yes_entered){` loop.

One other thing,  these lines:

```
characterName = malloc(sizeof(char));
yes_no = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

are going to cause you problems. You are allocating the two char arrays to be the size of one char. For this case you should probably consider picking a maximum character length and then making these two variables static char arrays. something like:

```
char characterName[MAX_NAME_LENGTH] ;
char yes_no[MAX_CONF_LENGTH];
```